# CSS: How to make a custom input's label overflow into the background and not over it?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

So I have a number input made with `styled components` where there's also a label that sits next to it in for form of a `span`:

[image]

and the css for this:

```
input {
  display: block;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: ${(props) => (props.option === true ? '0px' : '')};
  line-height: 19px;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 40px;
  width: ${(props) => (props.numberInputWidth)};
  padding: 0 8px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  white-space: nowrap;

  &:focus {
    border-color: ${COLORS.LIGHTGREEN};
    transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;

    ${({ error }) => error && `
      border-color: ${COLORS.ERROR};
    `}
  }
}
```

and the label:

```
.label {
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 7px;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 40%;
}
```

and the invisible spacing inside the label:

```
.invis {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Which all works. However, when a user inputs a very long integer, the placeholder will flow out of the container, which I assume it's because it's positioned absolutely:

[image]

For posterity's sake, here's the container holding the elements:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Is it possible to not make the label/placeholder not overflow OVER the container, but rather overflow within the container and behind/under the container? Sort of like this:

[image]

where the percent sign is cut off slightly.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="container">
  <input type="number" />
  <span class="label"><span class="invis">**invisible value for spacing here**</span> seats</span>
</div>
```

I've tried a few things in the container and I'm sure it's the culprit to getting this to work. Any help is much, much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `text-overflow: ellipsis;` for input box so if you have large number then also it will not go outside the box.

```css
.b {
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 120px;
    height: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 23px;
    border-radius: 13px;
    border-color: red;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<!-- The number is very large but it will not go outside the input box. -->

<div class="b">123456789012345678901234567890</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To use ellipsis, you have to assign absolute width,,, how would I do it if I have 3 inputs in flex container(with relative width), where width of each element depends on current width of the screen?